# How can I select multiples cell of the same row in a grid view?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

I have a Grid view and I need select multiples cell of the same row but if i click a cell in a different row i have to clear the previous selection and start a new selection with the last clicked cell.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the documentation: [Multiple Row and Cell Selection](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/711/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Focus-and-Selection-Handling/Multiple-Row-and-Cell-Selection)

> To enable multiple cell selection mode, set the
>   [ColumnViewOptionsSelection.MultiSelect](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnViewOptionsSelection.MultiSelect.property) property to `true` and the
>   [GridOptionsSelection.MultiSelectMode](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridOptionsSelection.MultiSelectMode.property) property to
>   [GridMultiSelectMode.CellSelect](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridMultiSelectMode.enum).

**Note:** This selection mode, supported by `GridView` and `BandedGridView`, allows an end-user to select contiguous blocks of cells as well as individual cells within different rows.

**References:**
[XtraGrid Multiselect Cell](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B92555/xtragrid-multiselect-cell)
[Cut multiple cells in a XtraGrid and Multi Select Drag & Drop data rows into another grid](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q158961/cut-multiple-cells-in-a-xtragrid-and-multi-select-drag-drop-data-rows-into-another-grid)

example code snippet:

```
using DevExpress.XtraGrid;
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base;

private void gridControl1_ProcessGridKey(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if(e.Control && !e.Alt && !e.Shift && (e.KeyCode == Keys.Home || e.KeyCode == Keys.End)) {
        ColumnView view = ((GridControl)sender).FocusedView as ColumnView;
        if(view != null)
            view.ClearSelection();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quickly answer but it didn't work, I implemented ProcessGridKey event, but I keep selecting cell of different row. I think my question wasn't clear enough, I nedd select multiples cell of the same row but if i click a cell in a different row i have to clear the previous selection and start a new selection with the last clicked cell.